# Error on Publish Android Leaked GCP API Keys

Tags: android, publish, android-security

While submitting build, I got pre-launch report details that my build is Leaked GCP API Keys
and after following this url https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/9287711 still not get clear step for the workaround

need input how to solve this?
is it save to put key on manifest as per describe here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-hide-api-and-secret-keys-in-android-studio/?
is the error will blocking the Playstore review?

1. set restricted on Android from GCP
2. put firebase key in firebase.gradle and access it through Build.Config